# How to Consume Binary Data at Jersey?

Tags: java, post, jersey

How can I write a controller to consume that at Jersey?

```
curl 'http://localhost:1111/alo/update/mi?ret=true' --data-binary @books.json -H 'Content-type:application/javabin'
```

I want to retrieve both the value of ret parameter and books.json as binary?

PS: javabin is a custom binary format.

Answer (score 1):

Post Base64 encoded string of binary data and decode that and another side.

Comment: I want to write a controller: a Java class

Comment: Yes inside controller accept String parameter and when you post data to controller convert your binary data into a base64 encoded string and post to that controller. inside controller you could decode that string into binary. you could find lot of link on net about use of Base64 in java.